# Writing gradient fill in python with numpy similar to Photoshop's

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm curious as to the correct way to write a gradient fill operation in Python with numpy. I'd like my function to take similar arguments to Photoshop's gradient fill:

[image: Gradient Fill]

For my current task, I'm most interested in the angle parameter. I have a working solution that creates a gradient image at 0 degrees and then rotates it, but I believe it would be more efficient to generate the image directly.

My working solution:

```
import vtool as vt
# Parameters
dim = 9
theta = np.pi / 8
# Create an empty patch
patch = np.zeros((dim, dim))
# Fill it with a horizontal gradient. 
patch[:] = np.linspace(0, 1, dim)
# Rotate the image around its center to achieve the desired angle
patch = vt.rotate_image(patch, theta, border_mode='replicate')
```

My rotate image function is just an underlying call to opencv that builds the appropriate translation/rotation/undo-translation matrix, and calls cv2.warpAffine with lanczos interpolation to rotate an image about its center.

My idea for a better solution involved using sin/cos functions to determine the line the gradient should move along, but it seems like I'd have to do the same sort of interpolation (and manually at that; instead of using opencv) to generate the image.

So, that brings my to my question: is my working solution the correct way to implement this or is there a better way? If so what is it?

Comment: what is the vtool module you are importing?

Comment: old package I used to use a lot. You can pip install vtool_ibeis which exists on pypi (vtool name was taken). But its just an image rotation.